# Should I worry about DoS attacks to files in static_dir?

Tags: google-app-engine

I'm thinking to implement a feature which blocks DoS attacks in Google App Engine for GO.
First I thought to implement it in the main request handler function but now I wonder "what about files in static_dir?
Should I worry about that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Static files are not served by your application directly so can't be DoS'd as such. The attacker would be attacking Google, not your instances.

See this question for more details: [Does Google App Engine use google CDN to distribute static resources?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2704789/does-google-app-engine-use-google-cdn-to-distribute-static-resources)

Where on one of the linked presentations it's noted that

> requests for Static Content on Google Network are routed to the
>   nearest Google datacenter.

So no, you probably don't have to worry about an attacker being able to make those resources unavailable to other users.